# Antiderivative of infinitely often differentiable function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Define interval $I=(0, 1)$, $C^{\infty}(I)$ as a ring of infinitely often differentiable functions from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $C^{\infty}_C(I)\subset C^{\infty}(I)$ an ideal of functions having compact support. Set $d\colon C^{\infty}(I)\to C^{\infty}(I)$ and $\bar{d}\colon C^{\infty}_C(I)\to C^{\infty}_C(I)$ a usual differentiation.

Is it true that $\text{Im}(d)=C^{\infty}(I)$ and $\text{Im}(\bar{d})=C^{\infty}_C(I)$? In other words, is it true that antiderivative $F$ of $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$ also lies in $C^{\infty}(I)$ and same for $C^{\infty}_C(I)$? If not, how can one describe $\text{Im}(d)$ and $\text{Im}(\bar{d})$?

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivative of $f\in C^\infty(I)$ is also in $C^\infty(I)$. It is not in $C_c^\infty(I)$ (even if $f\in C_c^\infty(I)$) unless $\int_I f =0$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a clue which finctions do not belong to $\text{Im}(\bar{d})$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f\geq 0$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(0,1)$ and let $F\in C_{0}^{\infty}(0,1)$ be its anti-derivative, assume further that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx>0$, then for some large $N$, we have $F(x)=0$ for all $x\in(0,1/N)\cup(1-1/N,1)$. Now express $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ for some $a\in(0,1)$. And we know that $\displaystyle\int_{1/n}^{1-1/n}f(t)dt\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, find some $M>0$ large enough such that $1/M\in(0,1/N)$ and  $1/M<a$, and that $\displaystyle\int_{1/M}^{1-1/M}f(t)dt>0$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1/M}^{1-1/M}f(t)dt=\int_{1/M}^{a}f(t)dt+\int_{a}^{1-1/M}f(t)dt=-F(1/M)+F(1-1/M)=0,
\end{align*} 
a contradiction, so $F$ cannot be compactly supported.

Comment: This shows that if $f$ is nonnegative and infinitely differentiable on the interval, and assume that the integral is non-zero (the integral must at least nonnegative in this case), then the anti-derivative cannot be compactly supported in the interval.